# C and OpenCV compilation error

Tags: c, opencv

I am trying to compile my first program with using *OpenCV* library. My code (file is named '1.c'):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "opencv/cv.h"
//#include <opencv/cv.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage (argv[1], 1);
    cvNamedWindow("Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("Example1",img);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage(&img);
    cvDestroyWindow("Example1");
}
```

and CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( 1 )
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( 1 1 )
target_link_libraries( 1 ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

When I am running *CMake* it works correctly, but running *Make* gives me output like this:

```
CMakeFiles/1.dir/1.c.o: In function `cvPointFrom32f':
1.c:(.text+0x559): undefined reference to `cvRound'
1.c:(.text+0x56f): undefined reference to `cvRound'
CMakeFiles/1.dir/1.c.o: In function `cvReadInt':
1.c:(.text+0xda0): undefined reference to `cvRound'
CMakeFiles/1.dir/1.c.o: In function `cvEllipseBox':
1.c:(.text+0x101d): undefined reference to `cvRound'
1.c:(.text+0x103f): undefined reference to `cvRound'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I saw other people having the same problem, but I couldn't solve my case even applying their solutions. I'm using *OpenCV 3.1.0*.

Comment: Don't use **obsolete** C api!

Comment: Yeah don't use C api, as I am writing C program not C++ so I should write in C++ and then make externs? what a stupid approach